# Why is the street “weeping”?

Tags: water, wet

There is a section of street outside my home that is always wet, even when hot and dry outside. The neighborhood is under construction (all new homes).  I have not experienced any plumbing issues. Why might it be doing this?

[image: wet street]

[image: close-up]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement.

Comment: Water main leak? Have you asked the city? Natural spring?

Comment: I have not asked the city yet. Wasn’t sure what it could be.

Comment: Looks like a seeping leak. Maybe a stress fracture on the water main (you probably have lots of heavy construction vehicles going over it). You wouldn't notice anything wrong in your plumbing because the water pressure and the small size of the crack keep the sediment out. I would report it, but the construction company that built the road might be more content to leave it until they're done building, rather than repair it and have more heavy vehicles break it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wet spot in your street could be from 1) broken waterline, 2) broken storm sewer line, or 3) natural well.

Obviously it’s a rising watertable and appears wet in that location because of the type of “fill” in that location.

Comment: It turned out to be a broken waterline and they have fixed it now. Thanks!